# QGIS3 georeferencing an unreferenced PNG and it isn't showing up on my base map

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, qgis-3, georeferencing, ground-control

I'm using QGIS3 to try to georeference a screenshot of an old map of a state park (the PNG file) to a shapefile of the park's boundaries by matching points in the park's boundary. When I tell it to start georeferencing, it generates a new file (Adk_drainage_lakes_modified) that shows up in my list of layers, but the map itself won't appear on my base map. I've tried different numbers of GCPs (6-10) and different transformation types and resampling methods. I've gone through the steps in the QGIS online manual and searched for similar posts here.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or send me to a post of someone with the same problem?

[image]

Comment: The `dest X` and `dest Y` don't look like valid UTM 18 coordinates for this area (expecting around `500,000 ; 4,900,000`). Make sure to set the same coordinate system as the reference layer.

Comment: I can't see the status bar in the screenshot, but the orientation of the map canvas leads me to believe that the project is set to a conical projection, and so is the data you are trying to georeference with. It might be a good idea to reproject that to your target CRS before georeferencing.